# php file() triggers no Exception on valid URL

Tags: file, exception

```
    try {                                                                                   
        $antwort = file_get_contents('http://not_existing.notnotnot', false);                                                                                  
        if($antwort===false) echo 'ERROR';                                                                                                                                 
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $e->getMessage();                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }   
    var_dump($antwort); // returns string(0) ""
```

I get no Exception, no false, just empty content for every URL. A valid URL returns with this snippet the right content. Why can't I get exceptions for an invalid URL? 
I came to this question because a wget on the same server leads to a valid return, but with a php script I can't file() the same URL. Really weird and I have no idea how to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't throw an exception if the file isn't found; it will raise a warning-level error. Those are different things. [From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> An **E_WARNING** level error is generated if filename cannot be found, maxlength is less than zero, or if seeking to the specified offset in the stream fails.

You should check for a `false` return, as you do, and not expect to catch an exception.

Also keep in mind when fetching a URL that the remote server may return an incorrect status code (instead of the expected 404), causing your script to think the file exists when it does not. You may need to check for empty values (`""`) as well.

As a rule, you should avoid using `file_get_contents` to access files via HTTP. It's not terribly secure, and many hosts don't even allow you to use it that way. Instead, use cURL, which is specifically designed for retrieving data over the web, including via HTTP.